# Asp.net input type ="text" vs asp:textbox

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm new Asp.Net.I have input type="text" also I have css class  for input[type="text"]. So I have an asp:textbox. How  can I write css class for my asp:textbox which is a different css class then the one for input?

My asp:textbox takes properties from 
 .login-box input[type=text], input[type=password]

```
<div class="login-box" style="padding:70px 30px">
    <img src="Images\human.png" class="man"/>
    <h1>Login Here</h1>
    <p>Username</p>   
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" runat="server"/>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtError" CssClass="text-hide" runat="server">Incorrect username or password!</asp:TextBox>
    <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
</div>
```

My style.css below:

```
.login-box input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.text-hide {
    height:40px;
    border-color:Transparent;
    background-color:Transparent;
    color:Red;
}
.login-box input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    height: 40px;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Please help me..

Comment: start by placing your .aspx page here. Also have you tried anything yourself to solve the issue

Comment: add CssClass="class1 class2 classX" this is the way you can add multiple classes to asp.net webform elements.

Comment: The term "css class" is usually used for the name that is specified in the "class" attribute on the element. `input[type=text]` is a selector, probably before a block of declarations in a .css file (or style element) [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax). What exactly do *you* mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use CssClass property. Like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtError" CssClass="text-hide" runat="server">
```

This will turn into :

```
<input type="text" class="text-hide">
```

on the page

Comment: adinas , What does  CssClass="text-hide" in your code?

Comment: When using a webforms server control and you want to give it a CSS class you use  "CssClass". In this case we are telling the tag to use the CSS class "text-hide"

Comment: I wrote class for textbox but it takes properties from in class of input type=text

Comment: So overwrite them. in the class "text-hide"

Comment: for example if you have  input[type="text"]{color:red} and in .text-hide{color:blue} then the blue will override the red

Comment: adinas, Have I to write as below?

Comment: .text-hide {
    Height:40px;
    Border-Color:Transparent;
    Background-Color:Transparent;
    Color:Red;
    visibility:hidden;
}

Comment: Seems okay to me although you usually only use lower case so: .text-hide { height:40px; border-color:transparent; background-color:transparent; color:red; visibility:hidden; }

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a label, literal or panel all can be used with asp: prefix to show some message in ASP.Net Web Form.

You don't add messages in input fields like in your example

```
<asp:Label ID="txtError" CssClass="text-hide" runat="server" Text="Incorrect username or password!"></asp:Label>
```

After this you can reference this class in your CSS like this:

```
.text-hide {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Username

```
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" runat="server"/>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtError" class="text-hide" runat="server">Incorrect username or password!</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: please edit your question end add this, not as an answer.